# Add a new register allocation pass llvm

Tags: llvm, llvm-3.0, register-allocation

I am writing a new register allocation pass on llvm. I followed the instructions here http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html#the-machinefunctionpass-class.

The pass is not displayed in llc --help. I changed the greedy allocation algorithm to register by the name "greedier" and built. Even this doesn't seem to be reflecting in llc.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you should be looking in `llc` and not `opt` ?

Comment: opt can't be used for machinefunctionpass

Comment: Correct. Is your problem still unresolved ?Are you compiling at the top level after introducing your pass?

Comment: Are you doing a `make` at the top level of your llvm directory?

Answer (score 0):

Did you also look at this? http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html#using-existing-registries

Recently I implemented an register allocator and following these instructions I was able to register it perfectly in `llc` using LLVM version 3.6.2.